# is there a way to text message from your desktop, BUT have it sync with your iphone?

Tags: iphone, instant-messaging, chat, ichat

I want to send SMS messages via any Mac desktop application, however, I want to have the chat history in my SMS hisotry on my iPhone 4.  Is this possible??

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using the SMS features of [Google Voice](http://www.google.com/mobile/voice/).